# SimpleXML PHP script not parsing properly

Tags: php, simplexml

This PHP snippet isn't working:

```
<?php
$fille = simplexml_load_file("http://answers.yahooapis.com/AnswersService/V1/getQuestion?appid=dj0yJmk9OFRTTUI3NGdNNjREJmQ9WVdrOU5FZFBURzFqTkdNbWNHbzlNQS0tJnM9Y29uc3VtZXJzZWNyZXQmeD1iYg--&question_id=20080617101425AAmo159")
echo $fille->Question->Answers->Answer[0]->Content[0];
?>
```

Its purpose is to parse this XML file, and to get the first answer's contents.

```
 http://answers.yahooapis.com/AnswersService/V1/getQuestion?appid=dj0yJmk9OFRTTUI3NGdNNjREJmQ9WVdrOU5FZFBURzFqTkdNbWNHbzlNQS0tJnM9Y29uc3VtZXJzZWNyZXQmeD1iYg--&question_id=20080617101425AAmo159
```

However, upon runtime I get this error:

> **Parse error:** syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO in **/home/content/76/10008776/html/trysearch.php** on line **3**

Comment: Flag: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a **simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: Yes, sorry @aerox. It was a lack of attention. However, I am reluctant to delete this question, as "Repeated deletion of answered questions can result in your account being blocked from asking. Are you sure you wish to delete?" Could it just be closed?

Comment: If it gets a couple more flags it should go to the review queue for closure. (I've avoided down-voting as typos catch us all out sometimes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the `;` at the end of your line.

```
<?php
$fille = simplexml_load_file("http://answers.yahooapis.com/AnswersService/V1/getQuestion?appid=dj0yJmk9OFRTTUI3NGdNNjREJmQ9WVdrOU5FZFBURzFqTkdNbWNHbzlNQS0tJnM9Y29uc3VtZXJzZWNyZXQmeD1iYg--&question_id=20080617101425AAmo159");
echo $fille->Question->Answers->Answer[0]->Content[0];
?>
```

More generally, when you face an error like `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected XXX on line X`, check what's right before the line in question, it's mostly because you forgot something :)